# [ERROR]: Unknown column 'DamageModifier' in 'field list'

Tags: azerothcore

I installed the DB with updates and I got this error:

```
Opening DatabasePool 'wotlk_world'. Asynchronous connections: 1, synchronous connections: 1. MySQL client library: 5.6.42 MySQL server ver: 5.6.42 MySQL client library: 5.6.42 MySQL server ver: 5.6.42 [ERROR]: In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 4, sql: "SELECT entryorguid, source_type, id, link, event_type, event_phase_mask, event_chance, event_flags, event_param1, event_param2, event_param3, event_param4, event_param5, action_type, action_param1, action_param2, action_param3, action_param4, action_param5, action_param6, target_type, target_param1, target_param2, target_param3, target_param4, target_x, target_y, target_z, target_o FROM smart_scripts ORDER BY entryorguid, source_type, id, link" [ERROR]: Unknown column 'event_param5' in 'field list' [ERROR]: In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 54, sql: "SELECT difficulty_entry_1, difficulty_entry_2, difficulty_entry_3, KillCredit1, KillCredit2, modelid1, modelid2, modelid3, modelid4, name, subname, IconName, gossip_menu_id, minlevel, maxlevel, exp, faction, npcflag, speed_walk, speed_run, scale, rank, mindmg, maxdmg, dmgschool, attackpower, DamageModifier, BaseAttackTime, RangeAttackTime, unit_class, unit_flags, unit_flags2, dynamicflags, family, trainer_type, trainer_spell, trainer_class, trainer_race, minrangedmg, maxrangedmg, rangedattackpower, type, type_flags, lootid, pickpocketloot, skinloot, resistance1, resistance2, resistance3, resistance4, resistance5, resistance6, spell1, spell2, spell3, spell4, spell5, spell6, spell7, spell8, PetSpellDataId, VehicleId, mingold, maxgold, AIName, MovementType, InhabitType, HoverHeight, HealthModifier, ManaModifier, ArmorModifier, RacialLeader, movementId, RegenHealth, mechanic_immune_mask, flags_extra, ScriptName FROM creature_template WHERE entry = ?" [ERROR]: Unknown column 'DamageModifier' in 'field list' DatabasePool wotlk_world NOT opened. There were errors opening the MySQL connections. Check your SQLDriverLogFile for specific errors. Cannot connect to world database
127.0.0.1;3306;root;ascent;wotlk_world
```

Comment: "Cannot connect to world database"

Does it instantly close?

Comment: Instantly close

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

> [ERROR]: Unknown column 'DamageModifier' in 'field list'

It looks like your `world` DB is not up to date. So you need to update it properly. To do that you can either use the DB assembler script (`bin/acore-db-asm`) or manually importing the missing sql files from `data/sql/updates/db_world`.

To make sure your DB is up to date, check the name of the last column of the table `version_db_world` of your `world` database. It should match with the most recent sql file name of the direcotry `data/sql/updates/db_world`.

I recommend reading:

## [How to make sure that the DB is up to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55282167/how-to-make-sure-that-the-db-is-up-to-date/55282168#55282168)

Comment: I think you should check those DBs because updates imports are giving me error too: https://imgur.com/a/JtC2peM

Comment: I cannot reproduce such issue, probably you're doing something wrong. Have you checked that table I mentioned?

Comment: It says 2019_01_12_05 but I can' import the "2019_01_12_06" and the "2019_01_12_07" file idk why, but if I skip these then the worldserver crashing remains.

Comment: of course you should not skip any sql file. So the problem is that you are not able to import those 2 files. Why is that so? are you getting any error?

Comment: One of them is 12mb, maybe read the FAQ on the wiki, there is something about "mysql gone away" if that's your issue

Comment: Yeah that is the error message I tried it again, I could import the  "2019_01_12_06" sql now but the "2019_01_12_07" gave me the error message: "mysql gone away". I changed the max packet size to a really big number but the error remained.

Comment: Okay, it is solved now: Mysql was trying to read "my.ini" file, but I had "my-default.ini" in the mysql folder. Thank you all for your help ! ;)