# How to make sure that the DB is up to date

Tags: azerothcore

When installing/updating [AzerothCore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk) sometimes one encounters errors such as:

> [ERROR]: In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 3, sql:
>
> [ERROR]: Unknown column 'entry' in 'field list'
>
> [ERROR]: Unknown column 'dmg_multiplier' in 'field list'
>
> [ERROR]: Table 'acore_world.graveyard_zone' doesn't exist
>
> [ERROR]: Unknown column 'mindmg' in 'field list'
>
> ERROR: Your database structure is not up to date. Please make sure you've executed all queries in the sql/updates folders.

this usually means the database structure is not up to date.

More specifically, the local DB version is not aligned with the local core version.

This leads to the following questions:

- How to check whether the DB is up to date or not?
- How to understand what DB SQL updates are missing per each DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### UPDATE 2021:

The latest AzerothCore has now the **automated DB updater** integrated inside the core.

You just need to enable it via `worldserver.conf` by setting:

```
Updates.EnableDatabases = 7
```

Then your `worldserver` process will automatically update all DBs for you.

You need **latest AC** to get this feature.

---

### Original answer and explanation:

AzerothCore has three databases: *auth*, *characters* and *world*. All of them need to be properly up to date in order to start the server application.

Each database has a table `version_db_xxxx` which holds information about the database version inside **its last column's name**.

- auth DB has the `version_db_auth` table
- characters DB has the `version_db_characters` table
- world DB has the `version_db_world` table

The database version will be expressed in the format of `YYYY_MM_DD_XX` which is basically a date followed by a number (`XX`).

This value will be the name of the last column of such tables and it corresponds to the name of the last SQL update file that has been applied to that database.

The SQL update files can be found in the `azerothcore-wotlk/data/sql/updates/db_xxxx/` directory (where `xxx` is the database name):

- https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/tree/master/data/sql/updates/db_auth
- https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/tree/master/data/sql/updates/db_characters
- https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/tree/master/data/sql/updates/db_world

To make sure the database is up to date, one should compare (per each database):

- the last column name of the `version_db_xxxx` table
- the *most recent* sql file name contained in `data/sql/updates/db_xxxx`

(*most recent* in terms of most recent date. If the date is the same, the file having the highest pending number is the most recent)

If the values are the same, then the DB is up to date. Otherwise, the DB needs to be updated by importing all missing SQL update files in order.

Comment: Just a comment. I ran into a situation where my database was damaged and some of the tables disappeared. Then the world server started complaining that they were missing. It would be handy to have a "rebuild database" feature.

Comment: @B-Man you can just delete your world database and easily re-create it using the DB assembler. Just make sure to save your custom additions (if any).