# i applied all the db updates to my SQL server after compiling a fresh core, and getting this error, what do i do?

Tags: mysql, azerothcore

After i update my SQL with all the updates in DB_auth, db_characters_, and db_world on the github, i get this error

```
Opening DatabasePool 'acoreworld'. Asynchronous connections: 1, synchronous connections: 1.
MySQL client library: 5.6.42
MySQL server ver. 5.6.45-log
[ERROR]: In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 8,sql: "INSERT INTO graveyard_zone (ID, GhostZone, Faction VALUES (?,?,?)"
[ERROR]: Table 'acore_world.graveyard_zone' doesn't exist
[ERROR]: In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 9,sql: "INSERT FROM graveyard_zone WHERE ID = ? AND GhostZone = ? AND Faction = ?"
[ERROR]: Table 'acore_world.graveyard_zone' doesn't exist
MySQL client library: 5.6.42
MySQL server ver. 5.6.45-log
DatabasePool acore_world NOT opened. There were errors opening the MySQL conenctions. Check your SQLDriverLogFile for specific errors.
Cannot connect to world database 
192.168.0.18;100;ADMIN;BlizzLifeAdmin;acore_world
```

[The Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtwCN.png)

Comment: It seems that the Graveyard_zone table is named game_graveyard_zone, same with the event tables

Answer (score 0):

I understand you executed the sql updates, but this really tells that your DB is definitely **NOT** up to date:

> [ERROR]: In mysql_stmt_prepare() id: 8,sql: "INSERT INTO graveyard_zone (ID, GhostZone, Faction VALUES (?,?,?)"
>   [ERROR]: Table 'acore_world.graveyard_zone' doesn't exist

It is possible that some updates gave error and were not imported correctly.

I recommend reading:

## [How to make sure that the DB is up to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55282167/how-to-make-sure-that-the-db-is-up-to-date/55282168#55282168)

Answer (score 0):

Update: I reached out to Kaev (bless you) and he helped me with my problem. It seems like the MySQL server wasnt installed correctly so we just reinstalled a new server and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Opening DatabasePool '**acoreworld**'
...
Table '**acore_world**.gravey...

May be wrong DB-name? "acore_world" is not "acoreworld"